# unable to perform update on a transactional table

Tags: hive

I am unable to perform update on a table.

I have create the transnational table.

```
CREATE TABLE d_mat.mat_data( 
d_id int,  
dname string, 
dloc string) 
 CLUSTERED BY (  
dloc) 
 INTO 2 BUCKETS  
 ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
 OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' 
TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
```

I am using Hive CLI.

```
SET hive.support.concurrency=true;
```

> Error: Error while processing statement: Cannot modify
>   hive.support.concurrency at runtime.  It is not in list of params that
>   are allowed to be modified at runtime (state=42000,code=1)

```
UPDATE d_mat.mat_data SET dloc='Australia' where d_id=1;
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ask you admin to enable `concurrency`. it's not allowed using `set`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update a column which is **bucketed in the table(d_loc)**.

Hive doesn't support yet to update Bucketed columns.

Change your bucketed column to `d_id`

**Ex:**

```
CREATE TABLE mat_data( 
d_id int,  
dname string, 
dloc string) 
 CLUSTERED BY (  
d_id) 
 INTO 2 BUCKETS  
 ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
 OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' 
TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
```

**Insert value into table:**

```
hive> insert into mat_data values(1,"hi","das");
hive> select * from mat_data;
+----------------+-----------------+----------------+--+
| mat_data.d_id  | mat_data.dname  | mat_data.dloc  |
+----------------+-----------------+----------------+--+
| 1              | hi              | das            |
+----------------+-----------------+----------------+--+
```

**Update the table:**

```
hive> UPDATE mat_data SET dloc='Australia' where d_id=1;
hive> select * from mat_data;
+----------------+-----------------+----------------+--+
| mat_data.d_id  | mat_data.dname  | mat_data.dloc  |
+----------------+-----------------+----------------+--+
| 1              | hi              | Australia      |
+----------------+-----------------+----------------+--+
```

> Error: Error while processing statement: Cannot modify
>   hive.support.concurrency at runtime. It is not in list of params that
>   are allowed to be modified at runtime (state=42000,code=1)

This error is related to configurations as you are trying to `SET hive.support.concurrency=true;`
 and this property is not listed in whitelist parameters.

To fix this issue change `hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist in Ambari`.

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/92240/it-is-not-in-list-of-params-that-are-allowed-to-be.html) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/74956/cannot-modify-hiveexecmaxdynamicpartitionspernode.html) link for more details.